# How to resize checkboxes in devextreme <dx-tree-view> with Show Check Boxes Mode: normal

Tags: css, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I'm explore the DevExtreme library and I've run into a problem with resizing checkboxes in `<dx-tree-view>`.

If I just create a `<dx-check-box>` it has a property that can set the size of the checkbox `[iconSize]="'15px'"` which I used when I wanted to reduce the size of the checkbox.
There is also a `<dx-tree-view>` tree where I set the `Show Check Boxes Mode: normal` option. And I would like to reduce the size of checkboxes in it to 15px, but the `[iconSize]` property of the tree doesn't.

How can I reduce the size of checkboxes in the tree correctly?
I tried to set these sizes via css:

```
.dx-checkbox-icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

And checkbox becomes smaller, but the check mark inside it does not change.

Here are some examples:
[case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z31oc.png),
[case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUHVk.png)

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of research, I achieved what I wanted.
Maybe this will help someone and save their time:

```
:host::ng-deep {     
   .dx-treeview-item {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 28px;
      min-height: 20px;
    }
    .dx-treeview-toggle-item-visibility {
      top: -3px;
    }
    .dx-checkbox {
      .dx-checkbox-icon {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
      }
      &.dx-checkbox-indeterminate {
        .dx-checkbox-icon {
          font-size: 10px;
        }
      }
      &.dx-checkbox-checked {
        .dx-checkbox-icon {
          font-size: 12px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I used SCSS to override styles.